# Should informal titles such as the "Father of modern physics" be in title case?

Tags: capitalization, formatting

How should text containing descriptions such as the following be formatted?

*He was dubbed as the father of modern physics.*

Should "father" "modern" and "physics" be capitalised? 
Should there be quotation marks around *father of modern physics*?

If it requires quotation marks, should they be single or double quotation marks (for both British and American English)

Thanks a ton!

Comment: I would capitalise none of those words, probably avoid 'dubbed', unless I was prepared to say who had done the dubbing, and write _He was (or is) called by some the 'father of modern physics'._ In general, British style prefers single quotes, US style double, but if you are writing for a publication, or acadermically, use the appropriate style guide.

Comment: @Michael Harvey Acadermically as opposed to skinformally?

Comment: Well observed. I should be flayed for that.

Comment: To the OP: of course, I meant to write 'academically'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey . . .  or flawed at least.

Comment: Lots of people do capitalize titles like this. [See Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=father+of+biology%2CFather+of+Biology&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfather%20of%20biology%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CFather%20of%20Biology%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfather%20of%20biology%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CFather%20of%20Biology%3B%2Cc0). To me, it seems more informal to capitalize them, although I don't know how other people feel.